# Android Realm occupying a lot of data space

Tags: android, realm

I am currently working on a CRM Android app using Realm for saving records.
I am syncing the data from the web server. There 10 Tables.There was this one table that had around 450 pages, such that each page contains 100 records (100 row's data) 
After fetching 10 table's record , the data size of my app has grown to **118MB**.

> ***Is this much space taking normal for Realm?*** ---> 118MB.

Or am I doing something wrong with the Realm?
I have checked my records for the duplication. There's no repetition, each row is getting saved only one time.

That's how I am configuring Realm in my 
**Application class**

```
realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);
```

And later on I am using the Default instance wherever I need it. And closing the Realm on the onTerminate of Application class

More Info: 
Android studio Version = 2.1.3

Realm Version = 1.2.0

Device = Nexus 5 Marshmallow

My Intent service for saving records in Database. It get's called after every page response.

```
public class SaveTableRecord extends Base_IntentService {

    private static final String ACTION_SAVE_RECORDS = "saveRecords";
    private static final String EXTRA_CLASS = "classVar";
    private static final String EXTRA_TABLE_JSON = "tabJson";
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "saveTableRecord";

    private String json, className;
    Realm realm;
    private Gson gson;

    public SaveTableRecord() {
        super("SaveTableRecord");
    }

    public static void startSavingRecord(Context context, String cls, String tableJson) {
        Log.i("Service", "SAVETABLERECORD.CLASS started");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SaveTableRecord.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_SAVE_RECORDS);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TABLE_JSON, tableJson);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CLASS, cls);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            className = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_CLASS);
            json = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TABLE_JSON);
            initGsonDataTypes();
            initRecordSaving();
        }
    }


    private void initGsonDataTypes() {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        //  builder.setLongSerializationPolicy(LongSerializationPolicy.STRING);
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(long.class, new LongTypeAdapter());
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(double.class, new DoubleTypeAdapter());
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(int.class, new IntTypeAdapter());
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(short.class, new ShortTypeAdapter());
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(boolean.class, new BooleanTypeAdapter());
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new GsonUTCDateAdapter());
        builder.setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        builder.setPrettyPrinting();
        gson = builder.create();
    }

    private void initRecordSaving() {
        try {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            showLog("-------------------InitRecordSaving()--------------------");
            final JSONObject main = new JSONObject(json);
            final JSONArray jsonArray = main.getJSONArray("records");
            //  String json = main.getString("records");
            //  saveATableRecord(json);

            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            String tableString = jsonArray.getString(i);
                            saveATableRecord(tableString);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            showLog("EXCEPTION A ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


        } catch (Exception e) {
            //   showLog("EXCEPTION!!!! SAVETABLERECORD CLASS");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void saveATableRecord(String tableData) {

        showLog("Table name =" + className + " AND Data = " + tableData);

        try {
            Class cls = Class.forName("com.oper.max.model.db.sync_tables." + className);
            Object obj = gson.fromJson(tableData, cls);
            // realm.beginTransaction();
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate((RealmObject) obj);
            // realm.commitTransaction();
            showLog("Object Added successfully");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // realm.commitTransaction();
            showLog("Exception in saveATableRecord = " + e.getMessage().toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you close the Realm instance on your background thread once you're done? Technically I'd need to see the background thread where you're downloading stuff and saving stuff.

Comment: I am using the Default instance. Regarding the thread, i am using an intent service for downloading all the records. Once data sync is done (which takes 10-12 minutes), the Intent service closes, hence the onTerminate of my Application class gets called and closes the data. 
I am not closing realm between the pause -> when once a row is inserted a new page is requested from the server and saved.

Comment: What kind of data ar you using? Please, write your realm class to understand. Imo, this is a too huge

Comment: The data coming from the server is just regular data containing strings,integers and long values.
We are getting the data page by page. There are like 400 pages, and one page contains approx 90-100 rows record. 
In the above code, initRecordSaving() is the method responsible for saving data, and its calling saveATableRecord in a loop to save row by row.

Comment: You do not close your Realm instance. -_-

Comment: Oops!!! I was closing on the onTerminate() of Application class, i thought that was enough perhaps... Sorry :) Let me check if it had an effect. Thank you!!!

Comment: `onTerminate` is never called :P

Comment: Alright. Even now i am closing my realm instance (like mentioned in the below answer as well) , My data is still growing very fast in MBs. And it ends near 90MB. Now i just want to know if that's normal ? For sync, i have around 20 tables,and they may have thousands of rows each.
I was wondering perhaps there's some insertion duplication, but there's not.My data is growing in MBs within a minute or two.

Answer (score 2):

You are not closing your Realm instance, and you should always close your Realm instance on non-looping background threads.

Change this:

```
private void initRecordSaving() {
    try {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        showLog("-------------------InitRecordSaving()--------------------");
        final JSONObject main = new JSONObject(json);
        final JSONArray jsonArray = main.getJSONArray("records");
        //  String json = main.getString("records");
        //  saveATableRecord(json);

        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        String tableString = jsonArray.getString(i);
                        saveATableRecord(tableString);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        showLog("EXCEPTION A ");
                    }
                }

            }
        });


    } catch (Exception e) {
        //   showLog("EXCEPTION!!!! SAVETABLERECORD CLASS");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void saveATableRecord(String tableData) {

    showLog("Table name =" + className + " AND Data = " + tableData);

    try {
        Class cls = Class.forName("com.oper.max.model.db.sync_tables." + className);
        Object obj = gson.fromJson(tableData, cls);
        // realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate((RealmObject) obj);
        // realm.commitTransaction();
        showLog("Object Added successfully");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // realm.commitTransaction();
        showLog("Exception in saveATableRecord = " + e.getMessage().toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

To this:

```
private void initRecordSaving() {
    Realm realm = null;
    try {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        showLog("-------------------InitRecordSaving()--------------------");
        final JSONObject main = new JSONObject(json);
        final JSONArray jsonArray = main.getJSONArray("records");
        //  String json = main.getString("records");
        //  saveATableRecord(json);

        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        String tableString = jsonArray.getString(i);
                        saveATableRecord(realm, tableString);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        showLog("EXCEPTION A ");
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //   showLog("EXCEPTION!!!! SAVETABLERECORD CLASS");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
}

private void saveATableRecord(Realm realm, String tableData) {

    showLog("Table name =" + className + " AND Data = " + tableData);

    try {
        Class cls = Class.forName("com.oper.max.model.db.sync_tables." + className);
        Object obj = gson.fromJson(tableData, cls);
        // realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate((RealmObject) obj);
        // realm.commitTransaction();
        showLog("Object Added successfully");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // realm.commitTransaction();
        showLog("Exception in saveATableRecord = " + e.getMessage().toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.Let me test it and i'll mark it as correct answer. 
Is this the case with background threads only ? Or should i close realm even after one query on the Main Thread as well or just at the end of app ?

Comment: `> even after one query on the Main Thread as well` that would invalidate your queries. The main thread auto-updates via the looper, therefore closing it isn't technically mandatory. Background threads cannot do that, so they must be closed, otherwise your Realm will grow very big.